# Can some tell me what gridTotalsCustomer in the following code?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

As per my understanding its path of grid block file. If yes, then I have my code in respective place then it's giving me an error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: gridTotalsCustomerJsObject is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):364)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="reports_report_customer_orders_grid"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.report.grid">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">gridTotalsCustomer</argument>
                <argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Totals\Collection\Initial</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.report.grid.export">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="exportTypes" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="csv" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">*/*/exportTotalsCsv</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="excel" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">*/*/exportTotalsExcel</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.report.grid.columnSet">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="count_totals" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">gridTotalsCustomerSet</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```